# How to convert the datatable into list of webelement in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am new to C# and I am using specflow

I am automating a scenario where multiple element needs to be checked if they are enabled. These elements are from different section of the page and have different xpath.

Approach I am thinking is

1. Convert the datatable  to list of webelements
2. Iterate over the list with

   ```
   foreach (webelement e in list)
   {
       element.isEnabled();
   }
   ```

I am planning to keep the element name same as the name given in datatable.

Have edited my question

**Edit**

My scenario

```
Scenario: Validate G Functionality
    Given Open URL
    When verifies fields
        | Gmail  |
        | Images |
```

Step Def

```
[When(@"verifies fields")]
        public void WhenVerifiesFields(Table table)

        {
           for(int i=0;i<=table.Rows.Count;i++)
            {


                IWebElement ew= table.Rows[i] as IWebElement;
                Assert.False(ew.Enabled);
            }
```

Page class:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Gmail")]
    private IWebElement Gmail;

    [FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Images")]
    private IWebElement Images;
```

I am getting following error

```
    Validate G Functionality [FAIL]
    [xUnit.net 00:00:06.38]       System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    [xUnit.net 00:00:06.38]       Stack Trace:
    [xUnit.net 00:00:06.38]         /*line pointed here is 
 ew.enabled*/C:\Users\StepDefinition\TestStepsOne.cs(53,0): at BillTrackerAutomation.StepDefinition.TestStepsOne.WhenVerifiesFields(Table table)
    [xUnit.net 00:00:06.38]            at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Table )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to convert datatable to a list of elements, here is a linq based example...

```
List<WebElement> studentList = new List<WebElement>();  
studentList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows  
        select new WebElment()  
        {  
            StudentId = Convert .ToInt32 (dr["StudentId"]),  
            StudentName = dr["StudentName"].ToString(),  
            Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),  
            MobileNo = dr["MobileNo"].ToString()  
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am not going to create the datatable. I already have the datatable. I am looking for ways to convert them to list of WebElements

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you create another datatable, it was provided to more clearly illustrate the process of a datatable being transformed into a list that you could then use to create your web elements. I've edited the example to only show how to transform a datatable into a list using linq.

Comment: Thanks . but can you provide the example,more inline with my requirement please,so that i can relate better.

Comment: I've edited the example to be List<WebElement>, hopefully that helps - as I don't know what is contained in your WebElement model or your datatable I can't do anymore - but you should be able to workout what needs to be changed inside new WebElement() to make that work?

Comment: Thanks for helping out but still not meeting my needs. I need convert my table to list of WebElement so that when I do the for loop on this list I can simple check for each element is enabled or not

Comment: Your original question was Question: how to achieve point 1;Convert the datatable to list of elements of the approach - my example shows you how to achieve that, good luck with the rest of your requirements!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a method to your page model would allow you to retain encapsulation of your web elements, but also provide a parameterized way to test the elements:

```
public bool IsFieldEnabled(string fieldName)
{
    switch(fieldName)
    {
        case "Gmail":
            return Gmail.Enabled;
        ...
    }
}
```

The step:

```
When verifies fields
    | Field  |
    | Gmail  |
    | Images |
```

The step definition:

```
[When(@"verifies fields")]
public void WhenVerifiesFields(Table table)
{
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
       var isEnabled =  yourPageModel.IsFieldEnabled(row["Field"]);

       Assert.False(isEnabled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `[StepArgumentTransformation]`

```
  Scenario Outline: examples with step argument
  Given we have '<Webelements>'

  Examples:
  | Webelements | 
  |     Gmail   |
```

And step definitions are:

```
  using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
  using NUnit.Framework;

[Binding]
   public class Browser
  {
     private readonly BrowserDriver _browserDriver;
     public static  OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver driver ;

      public Browser(BrowserDriver browserDriver, FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        _browserDriver = browserDriver;  //your chrome driver
        driver = _browserDriver._driver;
        _featureContext = featureContext;
        _featureContext.Add("driver", driver);
    }

     [Given(@"we have '(.*)'")] 

    public void webelements(ChromeWebElement o)
    {
       Assert.False(o.Displayed);
    }

    [StepArgumentTransformation]
      public ChromeWebElement convertToWebElement(string c)
      {
        ChromeDriver parent = _featureContext.Get<ChromeDriver>("driver");
        return new ChromeWebElement(parent, c);
    }
```

And obviously you get result `element is not attached to the page document` because I just used a `Gmail` for test purpose

But it is converting string to `ChromeWebElement` class (thats why you get that error).

Note that you can not convert to `IWebElement` directly because it is an interface

Also , note that you can not use `[StepArgumentTransformation]` with specFlow tables. It is mentioned in `Restrictions` part in [here](https://specflow.org/2019/improving-gherkin-specs-with-specflow-step-argument-transformations/)